# javascript getting in array all different values for a key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to obtain from a given array of objects, all different values for a given key. Example:

```
 var arr =   [
      {
        "cod": 0
        "level": "INF"
      },{
        "cod": 1
        "level": "INF"
      },{
        "cod": 2
        "level": "INC"
      },{
        "cod": 3
        "level": "IND"
      }
]
```

`different_values(arr,'level')`

should return:

```
['INF','INC','IND']
```

WHat would be an easy way to achieve so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop over the array and get the specified property from each element. use them as the keys in an object to get rid of the duplicates, and then return the keys of that object.

```js
var arr =   [
      {
        "cod": 0,
        "level": "INF"
      },{
        "cod": 1,
        "level": "INF"
      },{
        "cod": 2,
        "level": "INC"
      },{
        "cod": 3,
        "level": "IND"
      }
];
function different_values(array, property) {
    var values_seen = {}; // for removing duplicates
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        values_seen[array[i][property]] = true;
    }
    return Object.keys(values_seen);
}
alert(JSON.stringify(different_values(arr, 'level')));
```

Comment: Yeah, I like this method of deduping.

Answer (score 2):

```
function different_values(arr, value){
    var res = [];
    for(var i=arr.length;i--;){
        if(res.indexOf(arr[i][value]) === -1){
            res.push(arr[i][value])
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/mdzLr4q6/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function different_values(arr,key){
    var diff=[];
    for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
        var k=arr[i][key];
        if(diff.indexOf(k)===-1)diff.push(k);
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using `for in` loops for arrays. `for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++)` would be better. Plus you get to cache the length of the array.

Comment: why should I avoid it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Answer (score -1):

```
function different_values(array, key) {

    var count = array.length,
        output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        output.push(array[i][key]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: You're not removing duplicates from the output array which is what the OP wants.

Comment: Oops didn't notice the word "different"

Answer (score -1):

Just loop through the objects in a for loop and push the level in a result array.

**Edit:** added indexOf to get unique values

```
function different_values (arr, key) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i in arr) {
        if (result.indexOf(arr[i][key]))            
            result.push(arr[i][key]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Make sure to correct your objects. You are missing a comma between the elements:

```
{
    "cod": 0
    "level": "INF"
}
```

should be:

```
{
    "cod": 0,
    "level": "INF"
}
```